# Firestore & Angularfire2: Is it array-contains or array_contains?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

Why is this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html) by Firebase team using `array-contains` while the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) by Firebase team using `array_contains`?

What is the difference between `array-contains` and `array_contains`?

It's the same problem with [Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1809#issuecomment-432599833).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `array-contains`, as shown in the JavaScript code samples.

Since the text is the same for all languages, it might not always use the operators/functions of the language that you're looking for. But I'm pretty sure it's supposed to use JavaScript syntax, so I'm not sure why the documentation text is different here. I filed a bug for it.